# NSMutableParagraphStyle: Some properties not working on iOS 10.3.2 and 10.3.3

Tags: ios, swift

Im trying to set a `NSMutableParagraphStyle` in the following way:

```
@IBOutlet weak var headline: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        style.maximumLineHeight = 15
        style.lineSpacing = 0
        style.alignment = .center
        let attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey : Any] = [NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle : style,
                                                         NSAttributedStringKey.baselineOffset : 0]
        
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: headline.text!, attributes: attributes)
        headline.attributedText = attributedString
    }
}
```

...which **doesn't change anything about the appearance** of the text on iOS 10.3.2 and .3. It works on iOS 9 and iOS 11.

I've added the `baselineOffset` which seems to solve the issue for some users ([radar](https://openradar.appspot.com/31034683)) - it doesn't help in my case. Is there any other workaround, or do all the users with 10.3.x now have to live with broken layouts all day?

EDIT:
@Larme I tried this, which doesn't work either:

```
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: headline.text!, attributes: attributes)
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.backgroundColor, value: UIColor.blue, range: NSMakeRange(0, 3))
        headline.attributedText = attributedString
```

EDIT: After testing matt's code on both iOS 10.3 and 11 devices, I've come to the conclusion that there's a problem when setting the line spacing and max height - setting text alignment works without restrictions. Even when not doing anything in code and just using the Xcode UI to set up my attributed text, I end up with the following result (notice the line spacing):

[image]

[image]

**iOS 11 Device**

[image]

**iOS 10.3.3 Device**

[image]

Comment: Try to add a another attribute from range 0 to 1? I remember about reading a bug where applying the attributes on the whole range might fail in some iOS versions.

Comment: @Larme please see my edit

Comment: Without having looked into it at all, I've noticed your code makes the assumption that the label has already been set with the `text` property when it is assigned to your IBOutlet. Perhaps iOS 10.3.x did not follow this pattern. Can you check the value of `let text = headline.text!` when `didSet` is called (by placing a breakpoint or printing to console). Perhaps try running this code inside your `viewDidLoad` method instead.

Comment: @JoGoFo good idea, but sadly it didn't work.

Comment: Hey @matt, I've changed the code a little bit so it makes sense now. This error happened while trying to remove some code which is unnecessary for the question.

Comment: I was still busy responding to your answer by adding screenshots and a more detailed explanation. My question includes setting the line spacing, which your answer ignores - this seems to be the problem I face, setting the text alignment works fine. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. this is definitely a bug that I see no possible way of working around of short of getting apple to patch it.

I'm sorry :(

Comment: Is it realistic that Apple fixes a bug on iOS 10 when iOS 11 is already out? Layouts must be breaking left and right with his issue...

Comment: I really don't know. It think it really depends on you gathering as much people as possible that are concerned by this bug and other unpatched iOS10 bugs and make lots of noise on their tech support and in forums and then maybe they'll decide making a bug-correcting pass on iOs10 is necessary.

Comment: Well, this is not the answer I was hoping for, but apparently there's no way around it at the moment. I'm going to post this to the Apple forums in the evening and link it in the main post.